# python __call__ magic method is class method or object method?

Tags: python, class, oop, magic-methods

I'm recently working on design patterns in python and I saw this in the singleton design pattern:

```
# THIS WILL BE USED AS METACLASS FOR OTHER CLASSES
class MetaSingleton(type):
    _instance = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instance:
            cls._instance[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance[cls]
```

And also I understood that `__call__` is class method.
But I remembered that I use `__call__` with `self` like this:

```
class myclass:
   def __call__(self):
      print('__call__ is called.')
x = myclass()
x()
# __call__ is called.
```

*(These two codes are not related to each other, they are just examples.)*

So  `__call__` method is class method or object method?

And also another question:
If it's class method, In which situations I can use it as a classmethod?

Comment: It's an instance method. If it were a class method, it would be decorated with `classmethod`. The name of the first argument is irrelevant. It can be `banana` if you want

Comment: "And also I understood that __call__ is class method. " That is incorrect. It is an *instance method* on a subclass of `type`. But it's not a classmethod.

Comment: Put another way: it's an instance method, but instances of metaclasses are classes.

Answer (score 1):

It's an instance method. If it were a class method, it would be decorated with `classmethod`. The name of the first argument is irrelevant. It can be `banana` if you want

*<sub>— from [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625054/python-call-magic-method-is-class-method-or-object-method#comment112509676_63625054)</sub>*

it's an instance method, but instances of metaclasses are classes.

*<sub>— from [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625054/python-call-magic-method-is-class-method-or-object-method#comment112509846_63625054)</sub>*